# Dockerfile location and path

Tags: dockerfile

I am learning about Dockerfile by following some examples and reading the docs. A Dockerfile has the following starting lines:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir /home/meteorapp
WORKDIR /home/meteorapp
ADD . ./meteorapp

# Do basic updates
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get clean

# Get curl in order to download what we need
RUN apt-get install curl -y \

  # Install Meteor
  && (curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh) \

  # Build the Meteor app
  && cd /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app \
  && meteor build ../build --directory \
  # and more lines ...
```

The lines `&& cd /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app \` fails with error:

> /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app

The Dockerfile is located in the root directory of my app 
[image]

What is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `/home/meteorapp/meteorapp/app` doesn't exist inside your docker container.

When you `ADD . ./meteorapp` you put everything you have in the Dockerfile folder inside your container, so if you don't have an app folder (and it seems that you don't, based on your screenshot), it won't magically appear inside the container

Comment: And how to fix it? Move the Dockerfile outsdie the hp folder, and put it and the hp folder in a seperate folder? or change app to hp?

Comment: I guess you could `cd /home/meteorapp/meteorapp` and you will be in the right folder no ?